# Deleting the function.prototype object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

In Javascript: the good parts by Douglas Crockford, under section 3.4 Reference, it says that:
Objects are passed around by reference. They are never copied, so

```
a = b = c = {}; // a, b, and c all refer to the same empty object
```

Following the same lines, suppose I have a parent class P, and I inherit it in a subclass SC something like this,

```
var P = function (){};

var SC = function (){};

SC.prototype = z = new P();
```

Now, whatever changes that I make in SC.prototype, same are visible in 'z' as well, which is consistent with book.
But if i 'delete z' , then still the SC.prototype object is unaffected (it exists). Why is it not modified/ removed?

Comment: You cannot delete a variable [reference], nor an object. [The `delete` keyword is only meant for *properties*](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: @Bergi `z` is a property of `window`.

Comment: @JosephSilber: OK. I hate implicit globals :-/ If it was really the intention to delete a property of the global object, that should've been marked with a comment or been written as `delete window.z`

Comment: @Bergi - Get in the line :)

Answer (score 1):

Because with `delete something` you just erase a binding named `something` - not an object itself. Quoting the doc ([**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)):

> Unlike what common beliefs suggests, the `delete` operator has nothing
>   to do with directly freeing memory (it only does indirectly via
>   breaking references).

BTW, strictly speaking, `delete z` for `z` defined as *a variable* (i.e., with `var z`) won't have even this effect:

> `delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect
>   on variable or function names.

Of course, if omitting `var` here was intentional, `z` binding will be removed - as it's actually no longer a variable, but a property of a global object instead.

---

You might say: 'Ok, but what if I delete `SC.prototype` instead?' Well, you can't: `prototype` is a non-configurable property of `SC` (as for any function), so attempt to delete it will just return `false` in non-strict mode. In strict mode it'll throw an Exception at you.

Comment: Thanks, i also had that common belief :)

Comment: I'd suggest checking [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#misconceptions) as well, it has a bit more said on common misconceptions about `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

`delete`ing an object reference doesn't touch the object itself; it just clears the reference. The object will then be garbage collected *if there's no other reference to it*.

Since `SC.prototype` retains its reference to that object, `delete`ing `z` doesn't actually delete the object.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I was under the impression tha delete frees up the memory as well.

Comment: @user2759694 - Glad to have straightened that out for you :)